# Angular - Material TABLE

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am having an issue binding my data to the Material table

interface

```
export interface IToDoList {

    ID: number,
    Comment: string
}
```

service.ts

```
getToDoList(ID: string): Observable<IToDoList[]> {
    return this._http.get(environment.BASE_API_URL + 'GetToDoList/' + ID)
        .map((response: Response) => <IToDoList[]>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

component.ts

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    bsaFollowup: IBSAFollowup[] = null;
    toDoList: IToDoList[] = null;

    dataSource = new DashboardDataSource(this._dashboardService)
    displayedColumns = ['Comment'];
    constructor(private _dashboardService: DashboardService{

    }
    ngOnInit(): void {

      ..some code
    }

}
export class DashboardDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
    toDoList: IToDoList[];
    constructor(private _dashboardService: DashboardService) {
        super();
    }
    public connect(): Observable<IToDoList[]> {
        return this._dashboardService.getToDoList('xxxxx');


    }
    disconnect(){}


}
```

html

```
         <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="Comment">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Commment </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.comment}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" ></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:displayedColumns"></mat-row>
            </mat-table>
```

When i ran the code the table is not displaying the column and I get error(using F12)

> ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and
>   iterables are allowed

**********************************************UPDATE**********************************************

I changed my service to

```
  getToDoList(psnlUID:string) {  
        return this._http.get(environment.BASE_API_URL + 'GetToDoList/' + psnlUID)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Component

```
toDoList: IToDoList[] = null;
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  ngOnInit(): void {
         this.GetToDoList(this.userID);
        this.dataSource = this.toDoList; // I get error 
    }
GetToDoList(PNSLUID: string) {
        this._dashboardService.getToDoList(PNSLUID)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.toDoList = data.result;

                  },
            error => console.log('GetControls Method: ' + <any>error, 'alert alert-danger'));
    }
```

I get error (from this.dataSource = this.toDoList;)

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error TS2322  Type 'IToDoList[]' is not assignable to type
>   'MatTableDataSource<{}>'.   Property '_data' is missing in type
>   'IToDoList[]'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to initalize the `MatTableDataSouce` with the data from your service, change your component code to the following:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.GetToDoList(this.userID);
}

GetToDoList(PNSLUID: string) {
  this._dashboardService.getToDoList(PNSLUID)
    .subscribe( data => {
      // Set the dataSource here
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data.result);
    },
    error => console.log('GetControls Method: ' + <any>error, 'alert alert-danger'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add #table `<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">`

if this doesnt work. can you reproduce in stackBlitz.
[Reference](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)

Comment: #table it did not work..however I updated my code trying to use  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(); ..but i get an error..i updated my above code